# Javascript Text Change on Interval in banner - no click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to set up a rotating text banner. The banner is created using inline style. However, my script seems to be over-riding my inline styling.

Here is what I have:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()
```

```css
   div.textContent { display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="textMessage"></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px !important; background-color:#003768 !important; color:#8DC63F !important; font-size:27px !important;"><em>
  Outsourcing ATMs - the smarter solution.</em>
</h2></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Who spends ALL DAY on ATM Management? <span style="color:white";>Outsource ATM</span></em>
</h2></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Quality service companies anticipate the needs of their clients by providing solutions - not more work.</em>
</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ow9h3vxq/1/ ? where are the other styles

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ow9h3vxq/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `text()` to `html()`

https://jsfiddle.net/4aj7kg2q/

```
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).html();// html if you want to keep styles
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `textContent` element inside the `textMessage` element instead of just moving the text content

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var cnt = 0,
    $texts = $('.textContent');


  function slide() {
    if (cnt >= $texts.length) cnt = 0;
    $('#textMessage').html($texts.get(cnt++));
    $('#textMessage')
      .fadeIn('slow').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
      }, 1000).fadeOut('slow',
        function() {
          return slide()
        }
      );
  }
  slide()
});
```

```css
div.textContent {
  display: none;
}
#textMessage div.textContent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textMessage"></div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px !important; background-color:#003768 !important; color:#8DC63F !important; font-size:27px !important;"><em>
  Outsourcing ATMs - the smarter solution.</em>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Who spends ALL DAY on ATM Management? <span style="color:white";>Outsource ATM</span></em>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Quality service companies anticipate the needs of their clients by providing solutions - not more work.</em>
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `});` to last line of javascript.
and modify in my style.

```js
$(window).load(function(){  

var cnt=0, texts=[];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++]=$(this).text();
});
function slide() {
  if (cnt>=texts.length) cnt=0;
  $('#textMessage > div').html(texts[cnt++]); // add div in #textMessage
  $('#textMessage > div')
    .fadeIn('slow').animate({opacity: 1.0}, 5000).fadeOut('slow', 
     function() {
       return slide()
     }
  );      
}      
slide()

}); /// add last line close .load(function(){
```

```css
.textContent { 
  display:none;
}

#textMessage {
  color:#fff;
  background: #0077CC; 
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding:20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #0363A8;
  height:80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhai" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div id="textMessage"><div></div></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px !important; background-color:#003768 !important; color:#8DC63F !important; font-size:27px !important;"><em>
  Outsourcing ATMs - the smarter solution.</em>
</h2></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Who spends ALL DAY on ATM Management? <span style="color:white";>Outsource ATM</span></em>
</h2></div>
<div class="textContent"><h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Quality service companies anticipate the needs of their clients by providing solutions - not more work.</em>
</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using animate to make a longer fade, just give [**`fadeIn`**](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) a number. You don't need to wrap `slide` in another function, it already fits.
I left the `$(window).load(function(){ ...` bit out, as it was missing `});` but isn't needed for the snippet. You will still need that in your code most likely. You're using `html` to write the text, but `text` to store it into `texts`.

*As a side note, if this was a social experiment to produce a lot of spam, good job. ;)*

```js
var cnt = 0,
  texts = [];

// save the texts in an array for re-use
$(".textContent").each(function() {
  texts[cnt++] = $(this).html();
});

function slide() {
  if (cnt >= texts.length) cnt = 0;
  $('#textMessage').html(texts[cnt++]);
  $('#textMessage')
    .fadeIn(5000)
    .fadeOut('slow', slide);
}
slide();
```

```css
div.textContent {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textMessage"></div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px !important; background-color:#003768 !important; color:#8DC63F !important; font-size:27px !important;"><em>
  Outsourcing ATMs - the smarter solution.</em>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Who spends ALL DAY on ATM Management? <span style="color:white";>Outsource ATM</span></em>
</h2>
</div>
<div class="textContent">
  <h2 style="padding:6px; background-color:#003768; color:#8DC63F; font-size:27px;"><em>
  Quality service companies anticipate the needs of their clients by providing solutions - not more work.</em>
</h2>
</div>
```